# Amcharts hides last date on stock type

Tags: amcharts

I use Amcharts to display stock data. Although I have updated the last data for chart (27 Dec 2018), the chart only displays data to 24 Dec 2018. I don't know how to configure it. Please help me.
Best regards.

[Here is the image of my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxqD8.png)

Comment: Try setting [`extendToFullPeriod`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#extendToFullPeriod) to true if it isn't already set. If that doesn't work, post a fiddle.

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle. Please review and help me. Thank you.
Sorry, I don't know how to embed in here. So please follow this link: https://jsfiddle.net/nguyendong6789/qv6ckoju/6/